# How to use OpenCV with dart:ffi on iOS

Tags: flutter, podspec, flutter-plugin, dart-ffi

I am developing a flutter plugin that uses OpenCV as a dependency to do some image processing. I created a bridge and initilized lookup function as mentioned in [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop). The basic sum function works, however as soon as I add

```
s.dependency "OpenCV2"
```

on my plugins pod spec file. My pod install fails

```
[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (/.../native_add/example/ios/Pods/OpenCV2/opencv2.framework)
```

Meaning there is some static library within the private pod. Thus I enabled

```
s.static_framework = true
```

on my podspec file and ran `pod install`. Pods get installed, and app runs too but now I get another issue telling that `dart:ffi` is not able to find the symbol.

```
2020-06-05 15:52:55.419438+0545 Runner[759:830306] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol (dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, native_add): symbol not found)
#0      DynamicLibrary.lookup (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:33:29)
#1      nativeAdd (package:native_add/native_add.dart:13:6)
#2      nativeAdd (package:native_add/native_add.dart:12:34)
```

So how to make `dart:ffi` find symbols while enabling static_framework. There are very few resources related to `dart:ffi`.

### Update

Lookup Function:

```
final DynamicLibrary nativeAddLib = Platform.isAndroid
    ? DynamicLibrary.open("libnative_add.so")
    : DynamicLibrary.process();

final int Function(int x, int y) nativeAdd = nativeAddLib
    .lookup<NativeFunction<Int32 Function(Int32, Int32)>>("native_add")
    .asFunction();
```

C++ function

```
extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default"))) __attribute__((used))
int32_t native_add(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Show your Dart lookup code.

Comment: Question updated. PS: It's exactly the same from the example app and works perfectly without adding `OpenCV2`  pod.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to include the opencv source as noted here? https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop#open-source-third-party-library or compile it yourself into a signed or vendored framework?

Comment: Interestingly, the documentation page was updated yesterday. But I don't think adding whole OpenCV source code to my project will be a good idea. BTW I fix it by writing the code directly on Runner Target and adding OpenCV on the actual Podfile. Things are working currently.

Comment: Could you create an answer to document the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after couple of days of research. At the time of this writing(2020-06-07), I found that having a static framework on a flutter plugin code is not possible(I might be wrong). For more details [check here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33227#issuecomment-584457464)

But here is how I solved the issue, I copied every custom `.cpp` file to my Runner target and used `dart:ffi` to call from the core target. Also the pod that I needed is now on main PodFile. Same with the android, change your CMakeLists file to point c++ files from Runner folder inside iOS and link them with the grad

Comment: Hi! I don't understood yet what you did. Could you share any project or example with me?